# AutoFixture: Unable to create an instance, probably no public constructor

Tags: c#, autofixture

I have a class (LoginService) that accepts in the constructor an IUser. This is for performing integration tests rather than unit tests, for that reason I don't want to MOCK these, I have some Unit Tests already and they are working great using Moq with fixture.

I setup my fixture:

```
  var fixture = new Fixture();
```

And then I want to be able to freeze a version of the IUser, I have tried the following but I couldn't get it to work, it complains that it can't create the instance, probably due to a no constructor.

```
  var user = fixture.Freeze<IUser>();
```

So I have managed to get it to work doing the following

```
  IUser user = new User();  // Create my IUser manually
  fixture.Inject(user);
```

and then finally create the sut and sure enough the instance is injected.

```
  var sut = fixture.Create<LoginService>();
```

So am I doing this correct? Can I not use Freeze and I should continue to create my IUser manually and inject it onto the fixture?

Comment: Of course I could take autofixture out of the equation but I think it comes in handy even when not mocking i.e. I could do            var user = new User();
            var sut = new LoginService(user);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's correct – If you want to supply a specific instance of `IUser` to the `LoginService` you have to inject it.

Just keep in mind that `Inject` will affect all subsequent requests (if any) for `IUser`.

Comment: ah ok, so meaning i will always get that instance? So this is the correct way of doing it then ?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Nikos Baxevanis is correct, but there are many ways to skin that cat.

If, instead of the same user instance, you want a *new* instance every time, you could also map `User` to `IUser`:

```
fixture.Customizations.Add(
    new TypeRelay(
        typeof(IUser),
        typeof(User)));
```