# AutoFixture: Freeze runtime type throws no public constructor error

Tags: c#, .net, moq, xunit, autofixture

My brain is fried at this point so apologies if this is a silly one:

I'm attempting to gather all types implementing an interface type at runtime using reflection and have AutoFixture create instances of them. Some of them have no parameterless ctor.

As a result, I'm doing a

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetTypesWithInterface<T>() where T : class
{
    var iType = typeof(T);
    return iType.Assembly.GetLoadableTypes() //another method which does as it's namesake implies
    .Where(type => iType.IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.IsInterface)
    .Select(t => FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(t) as T)
    .ToList();
}
```

And elsewhere calling the code with a:

```
protected List<T> AutoCreateSpecimenWithFixture<T>() where T : class
{
        return TypeLoaderExtensions.GetTypesWithInterface<T>()
        .Select(t => new SpecimenContext(Fixture).Resolve(t))
        // .Select(t => Fixture.Create(t, specimen))
        .Cast<T>()
        .ToList();
}
```

Before this is called, my Fixture is a:

```
 protected UnitTest()
{
    Fixture = new Fixture();
    Fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    CustomRegistrations();
}

private void CustomRegistrations()
{
    _settingsServiceMock ??= Fixture.Freeze<Mock<ISettingsService>>();

    Fixture.Register(() =>
        new OverrideRule(_settingsServiceMock.Object));
}
```

I've toyed with Freeze/Inject/Register above, with no joy. In my actual integration tests, doing:

```
var kek = Fixture.Create<OverrideRule>(); //works
_rules = AutoCreateSpecimenWithFixture<IRule>(); //throws no public ctor error :/
```

I've also looked at these but haven't gotten them to work yet as per the `AutoCreateSpecimenWithFixture` method:

[AutoFixture: how to CreateAnonymous from a System.Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546850/autofixture-how-to-createanonymous-from-a-system-type)

[AutoFixture: Unable to create an instance, probably no public constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421739/autofixture-unable-to-create-an-instance-probably-no-public-constructor)

Any help would be appreciated please and thank you.

Comment: I think the problem is that your specifying an interface (`IRule`) instead of a class (`OverrideRule`), and you cannot instantiate an interface, and as such it throws the error that said interface has no public constructor. Try `AutoCreateSpecimenWithFixture<OverrideRule>`, you can then cast that to whatever you want (event to the interface you want)

Comment: @MindSwipe AutoCreateSpecimenWithFixture is the name of the method that starts with the code ```return TypeLoaderExtensions.GetTypesWithInterface<T>()``` (I've since edited the post to make that clear). As such it should have three concrete types (albeit one without a parameterless ctor) that Fixture should try to resolve, hence my hesitation to make that change

Answer (score 0):

I googled around some blogs and it looked like my seeds were being ignored, hence having to re-write my block to new up a seed as:

```
return TypeLoaderExtensions.GetTypesWithInterface<T>()
    .Select(t => new SpecimenContext(Fixture)
        .Resolve(new SeededRequest(t, null)) as T)
    .ToList();
```